# Entropy of chain decompositions of posets

Tags: co.combinatorics, posets, entropy, linear-extensions

Let $P$ be a finite poset and let $\,\mathcal{C}=(C_1,\ldots,C_\ell)\,$ be its decomposition into chains.  We can define
$$
f(\mathcal{C}) = |C_1|! \, \cdots \,|C_\ell|!
$$
and ask for what $\mathcal{C}$ we have $f(\mathcal{C})$ maximal.  Roughly speaking, the smaller is $\ell$ and the less evenly distributed are $|C_i|$, the better.  Specifically, I am interested in the following.

**Question:** *Does $f(\mathcal{C})$ maximize for the number $\ell$ of chains equal to the size of the maximal antichain in $P$?*

**Motivation:** If true, this would be an unusual extension of [Dilworth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem). I am really interested in bounds on the number $e(P)$ of linear extensions, and it is easy to see that $e(P)\le |P|!/f(\mathcal{C})$ for all chain decompositions $\mathcal{C}$. The connection to entopy is also standard: take $\log e(P)$ in the last equation and think of $|C_i|/|P|$ as a probability distribution.

**Refs disclaimer:** There is a large number of papers bounding $e(P)$ in terms of the entropy, see e.g. [here](http://www.cdam.lse.ac.uk/Reports/Files/cdam-2003-19.pdf), [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/theory/jehkim/papers/entropy.pdf) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.0086).  They are not completely unrelated, but do not seem concerned with this type of questions.

Comment: It seems clear to me that it does, and that for finite posets the function must achieve its maximum with a minimal decomposition.  I also don't see it as an extension at all, much less an unusual one. Gerhard "What Is The Question Really?" Paseman, 2016.10.09.

Comment: I am asking for a mathematical argument, not a POV.

Comment: Consider a poset P of width L+1, a decomposition of P that maximizes f, and look at a longest chain C in this decomposition. Since f is maximized, C is a maximal length chain. P-C is of width L. Recurse. I can fill it in if needed, but if there is a difficulty I am not seeing it.  If you could tell me what prevents you from this POV, we might have a more productive exchange.  Gerhard "Willing To Share A POV" Paseman, 2016.10.09.

Comment: The problem is the same as when trying to use the greedy algorithm to solve the knapsack problem. Namely, it is unclear if down the road you don't get into a situation with only short chains when compared to the case when you started with a second-longest chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **no**. Take a chain $a_1>\dots>a_{100}$ and add two elements $b>a_{51}$ and $c<a_{50}$ (with no relations not implied by these ones). The maximum of $f(\mathcal C)$ is achieved on the decomposition $\{a_1,\dots,a_{100}\}\sqcup\{b\}\sqcup\{c\}$, while the maximal antichain has cardinality 2 (due to the decomposition into two chains $\{a_1,\dots,a_{50},c\}\sqcup \{b,a_{51},\dots,a_{100}\}$).

Comment: Great!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Thanks for seeing what I missed.  Gerhard "Back To The Drafting Board" Paseman, 2016.10.10.